# Why Split behaves differently on different Strings?

Tags: string, scala, split

Here are the two cases :

**Case 1:**

```
scala> "".split('f')
res3: Array[String] = Array("")
```

**Case 2:**

```
scala> "f".split('f')
res5: Array[String] = Array()
```

Why does it behaves diffently here ! A concrete explanation would be great !

Comment: I saw this a few days ago on twitter: it was considered an undesirable and unexpected behaviour. I don't think there's a reason for it to behave like this.

Comment: Hm, this behaviour is well-documented.

Comment: `String.split` is defined in Java standard library, so it isn't a Scala question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In first case you provide a string and a separator that doesn't match any of characters in that string. So it just returns the original string. This can be illustrated with non-empty string example:

```
scala> "abcd".split('f')
res2: Array[String] = Array(abcd)
```

However your second string contains **only** separator. So it matches the separator and splits the string. Since splits contain nothing - it returns an empty array. According to Java String docs:

If expression doesn't match:

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

If expression matches:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

If you will look in implementation of split you will notice that it checks for index of delimiter inside String, and if delimiter don't occur in given String it will result with String itself.